# What happened to 'Listener' with a new version of Google Play Services

Tags: google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

(In Android Studio,) I have updated Google Play Services from

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11, to
com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87
```

which resulted in unresolved:

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.DriveEvent.Listener
```

Can anybody enlighten me on this issue? [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes) do not mention anything in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue also.  I believe it became ChangeListener.

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.events.ChangeListener;
```

Comment: Lack of adult supervision?