# Android: Google drive integration, what is "com.google.android.gms.version"?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

My application integrates with Google Drive using the old api, it does not include Google's library project (instead it includes a bunch of jars like 'google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar', 'google-api-services-drive-v2-rev59-1.12.0-beta.jar', etc...).

This causes an issue because this line in my manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Now gives the following error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value 
 '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

If I just copy the version.xml file from the library project into my project, the error goes away. The file's contents are:

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer>
```

But now I'm wondering, what is the `com.google.android.gms.version` attribute anyway? Is it the version number of the google play services on the device? Copying the file into my workspace seems the same as just hardcoding the attribute to '6587000'. If so, will this cause issues going forward if devices update their google play services? Will it cause issues on devices that currently have an old version of the services installed? (And in all these cases, how would importing this resource value from the library project be any better, as that just seems like a hardcoded value as well?)

Any general insight into the safety of this workaround?

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse? Basically, your IDE cannot find the 'version.xml' file. Check your setting. BTW, the last version of GooPlaySvcs (rev 23) is 7.00.00

Comment: If you were on Studio, I could point you step-by-step.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I understand how to resolve the error. I was looking for insight as to what the version number is, and if my resolution is likely to produce issues on legacy/future devices?

Comment: What you're doing is not harmful as long as you remember to edit it after pulling a new version of GooPlaySvcs (as I said, rev 23 is 7.00...). So you would have to change '6587...' to '7000...'

Comment: No, it is a standard indirection problem. You either point to 'version.xml' that has the number in it, or you hardcode it anytime you get a new 'version.xml' installed. GooPlaySvcs should be backward compatible, but in reality, they pulled rug underneath us a few times already, like changing method names.

Comment: Here's a typical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887854/what-happened-to-listener-with-a-new-version-of-google-play-services

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure if this is applicable in my case, because I'm not including the google play services, rather I'm including some jars which I believe expect the google play services to be installed on the device. for example, if I hardcode the version to some previous number, like 4030500, my app crashes with stack traces saying that version 658700 was expected. It works fine with 658700, but it is disconcerting?

Comment: @ab11 what is the latest insight you have on this?Want to know how it effects  legacy/future devices.  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html"

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder Honestly, I'm not working on this any more so there may be other options I'm unaware of. I believe the best idea is to simply add a dependency on the Google Play Service library as recommended by Google.

Comment: @ab11 my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808093/android-google-play-services-compatibility-if-phones-gps-is-not-up-to-date is unanswered yet..will figure how it holds up in my project and update soon..